# Accessing base nop model custom properties from a product id in nopCommerce

Tags: c#, properties, nopcommerce

I'm trying to access the custom properties of a product I have fetched by product id, but I really don't know how to go about this.

So if I grab the product like so:

```
var product = _productService.GetProductByIds(productId);
```

I would like to then access these properties with if statement:

```
product.CustomProperties.Keys.Contains("Popular")
```

Can't seem to find anything on this, can anyone help?

Comment: I dont understand, `CustomProperties` is a Dictionary? or you want to check if any  propertie in product is equal to Popular?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal yeah I want to check if the product has that property

Comment: So check if the type have a property called Popular? or if the value of some property is Popular?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal the trouble is product.CustomProperties is not available, it has error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `GetProductById`**s** return a list of products, and perhaps you intend to get a single product only. Thus, use GetProductById instead.

Also, there is nothing like *"Popular"* inside product model, possibly you'd have added custom one.

Finally, I assume that you'd like to check if the property exists within the product model or not! that can be done as follows,

```
var product = _productService.GetProductById(productId);
var productProperty =  product.GetType().GetProperty("Sku");
if(productProperty != null)
{
    //exists
}
else
{
    //doesn't exists
}
```

Comment: Hey @Div sorry have been out of office. Hmm this still doesn't work so really stumped on how to access the product custom properties

Comment: @WebDevvy, *this still doesn't work* is a broad word, you have to describe the issue or error in detail